# c++ failed to connect to mysql

Tags: c++, mysql

I get the following error message when I connect to mysql:

```
CDK Error: unexpected message
```

client is Ubuntu 19.04
server is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

The client library is: libmysqlcppconn-dev/bionic,now 1.1.9-1 amd64 [installed]

mysql server is version: 5.7.27-0

I can connect via the mysql command line client using the same credentials.

```
using namespace mysqlx;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Session s
    (
        SessionOption::HOST, "11.11.11.11"
        ,SessionOption::PORT, 3306
        ,SessionOption::USER, "xxx"
        ,SessionOption::PWD, "xxx"
        ,SessionOption::DB, "xxx"
    );
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
mysqltest 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mysqlx::abi2::r0::Error'
  what():  CDK Error: Broken pipe (generic:32)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same problem. Solution:

1. Using command line, log in to your mysql server using the following command:

```
mysql -u user -p -e "SHOW plugins"
```

2. Make sure the plugin `mysqlx` is actived.

```
+----------------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+---------+
| Name                       | Status   | Type               | Library | License |
+----------------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+---------+
...
| mysqlx                     | ACTIVE   | DAEMON             | NULL    | GPL     |
```

In my case it wasn't even on the list.

More information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/x-plugin-checking-installation.html